# Symfony only detects lowest php version

Tags: php, symfony, wampserver, stability

I installed Wamp64, comes with 3 versions of php 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1
When I try to create a new symphony project I receive this error:

> Could not find package  symfony/skeleton with stability stable in a version > installable using your PHP version 5.6.31.

Obviously I need to activate php7 which I did, I restarted wamp services(apache ...etc) and I still get the same error. Please [see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THZfD.jpg)

Comment: Output of `php -v` ? I suspect your `PATH` environment variable still points to the 5.6 executable.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP path probably points to the bad PHP version.
Try to type

```
php -v
```

If the version is not good you can change it by changing your path by typing, environment variable in your Windows search bar.
After that edit the value of the var `Path` and add the PHP bin folder

For me :

```
C:\PHP\bin\
```

And that's all

(Try to learn docker or install your development environment manually and use PHP built-in server to run your project, wamp is good when you start but you don't know how all work and this is bad :( )

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue :

```
php --version
PHP 7.3.9 (cli) (built: Feb 17 2020 12:46:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.9, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

But symfony always output :

```
Could not find package symfony/website-skeleton with stability stable in a   
 version installable using your PHP version 5.6.30.
```